# Woocommerce Cart total not working. always gives 0

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

I am trying desperately to get something that is simple. I know it's simple, I have done it many times before but it is not working and driving me insane.

I want the cart total in php for my woocommerce cart. so I can compare the value and determine if it is at a point where I initiate other functions.

this is what I have tried and in every case it returns either "0" or a string in which the cart value is again, 0.

string example:

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>0.00</span>
```

the methods I have tried using are as follows, this is right in the woocommerce docs but they give no useful information:

```
$total         = $woocommerce->cart->get_total();
$total_a       = WC()->cart->get_total();
$total1        = $woocommerce->cart->get_total_ex_tax();
$total1_a      = WC()->cart->get_total_ex_tax();
$total2        = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
$total2_a      = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
$total_testy   = $woocommerce->cart->total();
```

from past experience some of these would just give me the total in an integer and away I go. now they give nothing but 0. can anyone see why this is not working?

Comment: Go to the actual /cart and see if you got anything there. Are these simple products you add to cart?

Comment: I am on the cart page. and the checkout page, and the homepage testing. there is a simple and a variable product in the cart while testing.

Comment: You using a theme or Woocommerce default template? Could you paste the entire template code here with the name and path?

Comment: no? that would be insane. I will test further on my test server with wp default themes but this is basic functionality of Woocommerce. also I can get anything else from the cart object, like individual product prices. I could pull out every individual product, gather its price and tax data and then add all cart items together to get the total. What I am wondering is why, when I can clearly access these objects and information is getting just the cart total so hard and always giving a 0.00 amount result?

Comment: subscription products with free trial would have total 0. If you don't show more code, there's not much to work with though.. var_dump $woocommerce->cart gives the correct content?

Comment: **It depends where you are using this code**… `WC()->cart` *(the right modern syntax)* works on fronted… The `WC_Cart` methods that you are using will give you mostly formatted html data, but not integer or float values… For that you can access directly in this class the cart properties. Also for example in some cases like in `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook  the only accessible total is `WC()->cart->cart_contents_total` … so please **be more explicit telling where and how you are using your code**…

Answer (score 1):

the issue I ran into was the result of the hook location I was using. I was using a hook that fired before the cart total was calculated due to me wanting to edit product prices based off the cart total and manipulate them before calculating the total. by using the following wc hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total', 'my_function', 99 );
```

I was able to get the value of the cart total and make my price changes based off the result and injecting it into another function.

so there is a basic thing that caused me a lot of frustration, be cautious of hooks and where they trigger.